# How to create the cross domain using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

*Hi, I need to create a dropdown list which uses a cross domain to populate it. And i have set a url for it but couldn't find why it is not working .
 When the url is in json format  it works without any issues but the url is in a xml format. And this is my first work on API's so  I will be thank full if anybody help me with this...*

---index.html---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <style>
    li span.ng-binding {
        color: #f00;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <h1>{{val}}</h1>
        <select ng-options="p.ProductName for p in Product"></select>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

---script.js---

```
var App = angular.module('App', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, AppFact) {
    $scope.val = "Testing the Page For CallsBacks";
    AppFact.getData(function(Product) {
        $scope.Product = Product;
    });
})
.factory('AppFact', function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function(successcb) {

            var url = 'http://xxxxxxxxx';
            $http.jsonp(url).
            success(function(Product, status, headers, config) {
                //alert('ji');
                console.warn(Product);
                successcb(Product);
            }).
            error(function(Product, status, headers, config) {
                //alert(Product);
                //alert("Status is " + status);

            });
        }
    };
});
```

And Here is my plunker:http://plnkr.co/edit/qq8sELDdZZB5QKe1Pj3T?p=preview

*Plz guide me with this because i'm new to API's side..*

Comment: Are you building the API yourself? It is best to grasp a good understanding of CORS - a good point of ref - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: you appear to be trying to use `jsonp` on the client, but this isn't a `jsonp` endpoint.  You'll need to either reconfigure your server, or use a standard REST call and enable CORS.

Comment: did you try it with `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` added to the end of your URL call? i.e. `var url = "../ProductMaster?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";`

Comment: @ Shehryar yes i tried tat  but  i'm not getting any response